# Integrate Adobe Omniture in Unity iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have to integrate Adobe Omniture into my Unity Project. I managed to call most of the functions i need with Android but now comes the iOS part which makes problems.

Omniture comes with a *.a file (AdobeMobileLibrary.a) which must be the library itself, a header file (AdobeMobile.h) and a json file for configuration. The library is written in Objective C.
I put all these files in Assets/Plugins/iOS.

To call a function from the library named version() that returns a string i do

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
extern static string version();
```

signature of it in Objective C is

```
NSString *libraryVersion = [ADBMobile version];
```

Unity finely compiles but in Xcode the Apple-Mach-O-Linker says that there is no function called _version().
I checked if the header file, .a file and .json file are in the project unity created for me. I also tried to add the .a file to Buildphase -> Link Binary With Libraries but nothing helped.

Is it even possible to call pure Objective C functions in a C# script or do I have to write my own library written in c with some wrapper functions that call the actual Omniture functions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

When you first add (drag) the "AdobeMobile" folder into your Xcode project, confirm the following settings:

- Check the item "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)".
- Select the radio selection "Create groups for any added folders".
- Select the targets (your Unity app) where you want to use the Adobe AppMeasurement code.

During the Build Phases tab of your project’s target, expand the Link Binary with Libraries section and add the following libraries:

- libsqlite3.dylib
- SystemConfiguration.framework

Also, I found this post, which seems to clarify that you can call Objective C functions from Unity: [Passing complex data type from a pure c plugin to Unity C# scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216625/passing-complex-data-type-from-a-pure-c-plugin-to-unity-c-sharp-scripts):

> The basic functionality already works. That is, I already have a very
>   basic function call in my plugin to start a product request to the
>   Apple App Store which can be called from Unity. In the unity script
>   you simply call this method like this:
>
> ```
> [DllImport ("__Internal")]
> private static extern void RequestProducts(string[] productIdentifiers, int arrayCount);                          
>
> public static void RequestProductData( string[] productIdentifiers )
> {
>     RequestProducts(productIdentifiers, productIdentifiers.Length);
> }
> ```
>
> This calls the C function which looks like this:
>
> ```
> void RequestProducts(char* productIdentifiers[], int arrayCount)
> {
>     // Call the In-App purchase manager to initialize the product request
>     [[InAppPurchaseManager sharedInAppPurchaseManager] RequestProductData:productIdentifierCollection];
> }
> ```