# C++ serialize a class - data sent over a named pipe - deserialize in C#

Tags: c#, c++, serialization

What I am trying to achieve is this -
C++ DLL searches for bluetooth devices, on finding one instantiates a class and fills the new object.  This needs to be serialized, sent over the named pipe to a calling C# DLL that has a thread that reads from the pipe and updates the UI. Sending a string over the pipe works fine eg SendDataToPipe(_T("Phone\n")); but I will need to change parameter type to handle a class.  Not sure how to get the serialization and sending the result over the pipe.  This link [Serialize in C++ then deserialize in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726410/serialize-in-c-then-deserialize-in-c) looks good for the last piece of my puzzle. Moderators if this is to plain and not clear please just lock it and I will try again. Thanks.

```
UINT SendDataToPipe(LPTSTR data)
{
    DWORD numBytesWritten = 0;
    BOOL result = WriteFile(pipe, data, _tcslen(data) * sizeof(TCHAR), &numBytesWritten, NULL);

    if (result) 
        return numBytesWritten;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

In header file

```
class CFoundDevice : public CObject
{
public:
    CFoundDevice();
    ~CFoundDevice();
    DECLARE_SERIAL(CFoundDevice);

public:
    CString fdtype;
    CString fdname;

protected:

public:
    virtual void Serialize(CArchive& ar);

protected:
};
```

In cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FoundDevice.h"

IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(CFoundDevice, CObject, 1)

CFoundDevice::CFoundDevice()
{
    fdtype = "";
    fdname = "";
}

CFoundDevice::~CFoundDevice()
{
}

void CFoundDevice::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    DWORD dwVersion = 0x00000000;

    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        ar << dwVersion;
        ar << fdtype;
        ar << fdname;
    }
    else
    {
        ar >> dwVersion;
        ar >> fdtype;
        ar >> fdname;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: Sorry should have added -  the class definition header & cpp files are in a dll of there own and a reference to that dll is added in the references of my main C++ DLL. When I add the line CFoundDevice cfd; in the main C++ DLL it states that CFoundDevice is undefined.  That I think is probably just the first issue.